# How to handle “System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error”...?

Tags: exception, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, comexception

I am getting  **“System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error”** while rigorously switching between two user controls. I am developing application for Windows Phone 8.1 using C# and XAML in Visual Studio 2013.
If my understanding is correct(from internet and forums), this happens in many apps when we do rigorous navigation, and I was not able to get a specific solution for the same.
**Is there a way to catch this exception and prevent the application from crashing.**

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My app crashes when i am tapping on comboboxes continuously, it then crashes randomly. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have your `usercontrols` as `itemtemplate` in a `ListView`/`GridView`?
- Do you use the `ItemClick` event in the `ListView`/`GridView`?
- Do you navigate to another page within the `ItemClick` event?

Then this might help you...

Instead of `ItemClick` try to use the Tapped event from the root grid of your usercontrol. Somehow the `ItemClick` event is broken on Windows Phone 8.1, works perfectly on Windows 8.1 though.

Code example:

## Don't do this:

XAML

```
<GridView ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <usercontrols:MyUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Your navigation code...
}
```

## Instead try this:

XAML

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <usercontrols:MyUserControl OnTapped="ItemTapped"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Page code behind

```
private void ItemTapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // You navigation code
}
```

Usercontrol code behind

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler OnTapped;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RootGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnTapped != null)
        {
            OnTapped(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```